# react-youtube playerVars is not applied

Tags: reactjs, video, next.js, youtube

I am trying to add a video element using react-youtube. I have playersVars prop inside the opts object and even though other props such as width and height are applied the playersVars prop is not applied.

```
import YouTubeVideo from "@/components/ui/YouTubeVideo";

const VideoAd = () => {

  return (
    <div className={styles.videoAdContainer}>
 
      <div className={styles.video}>
        <YouTubeVideo
          videoId="J468yZ0plhA"
          width="800"
          height="450"
          playerVars={{
            autoplay: 1,
            loop: 1,
            controls: 1,
            showinfo: 0,
            modestbranding: 0,
            rel: 0,
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoAd;

"use client";
import styles from "./YouTubeVideo.module.scss";
import YouTube, { YouTubeProps } from 'react-youtube';

interface YouTubeVideoProps {
  videoId: string;
  width: string;
  height: string;
  playerVars: object;
}

const YouTubeVideo = ({ videoId, width, height, playerVars }: YouTubeVideoProps) => {
    const opts: YouTubeProps['opts'] = {
        height,
        width,   
        playerVars,
      };
    
      return <YouTube videoId={videoId} opts={opts} />;
};

export default YouTubeVideo;
```